# HTML CSS how to show elements with same width and different heights

Tags: html, css

I have many card-like elements all with the same width but differing heights that I want to show like this picture [image]

How could I achieve this using styling?

Comment: There's many ways. What you are describing is called "masonry layout". The current  "hot" way of doing it is "flexbox masonry".

Comment: ony styling CSS alone won't be enough, you can google something like Masonry layout and have a look, this is a quite common lib you can start out with https://masonry.desandro.com/layout.html

Answer (score 1):

CSS has property called columns, it offers you display element content in column layout, you can use it to achieve what you described.

```
<div>
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x60">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x80">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x120">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x140">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x160">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x180">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x200">
</div>
```

css:

```
div {
   columns: 100px auto;
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/x6bdft9u/

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/columns

it has been duplicate while I was answering, sorry